# Controller Action Not Found JSON and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

Hi I have this controller method

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CalculateModel.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            CalculateModel.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
            CalculateModel.BMICalc = CalculateModel.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateModel.Weight, CalculateModel.Height);
            CalculateModel.BMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIInfo(CalculateModel.BMICalc);

            db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        var data = new
        {
            CalculatedBMI = CalculateModel.BMICalc,
            CalculatedBMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIMeaning
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

And this is my JS functions:

```
 $('#good').click(function () {
    var request = new BMICalculation();
    $.ajax({
        url: "CalculateAndSaveToDB",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(request), //Ahhh, much better
        success: function (response) {
            $("#result").text(response.result);
        },
    });
    ShowBMI();
});


function ShowBMI() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "CalculateAndSaveToDB",
        success: function (data) {
            var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
            div.html("<br/> " + "<b>" + "Your BMI Calculations: " + "</b>");
            printBMI(div, data);
        }
    });
};
```

When ShowBMI() is executed, Chrome says `GET http://localhost:50279/BMICalculations/CalculateAndSaveToDB/0 404 (Not Found)`
The POST works as it saves to the database etc but the GET doesn't? Is there any reason for this? As you can see the URLs are exactly the same in each JS function so Im not sure why its found once nut not again the second time?

UPDATE:

After separating logic, the values appearing on the webpage are both null. See below for code changes

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(BMICalculation CalculateModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CalculateModel.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            CalculateModel.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
            CalculateModel.BMICalc = CalculateModel.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateModel.Weight, CalculateModel.Height);
            CalculateModel.BMIMeaning = CalculateModel.BMIInfo(CalculateModel.BMICalc);
            db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        CalculateAndSaveToDB(CalculateModel.BMICalc.ToString(), CalculateModel.BMIMeaning.ToString());
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CalculateAndSaveToDB(string o, string t)
    {
        var data = new
        {
            CalculatedBMI = o,
            CalculatedBMIMeaning = t
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you've applied the [HttpPost] attribute :) That attribute renders the action available solely for POSTing and not GETing. You should move the logic that is relevant for GETing to an action with the same name but without the [HttpPost] attribute and keep the logic for handling POSTed data in the action marked with the [HttpPost] attribute.

Be advised that you *should* reconsider the names when separating logic into different methods, or else the names will be misleading.

**Regarding your update**

I would have the POST request handling action (your action marked with HttpPost) return an ActionResult which in essence would mean that the POST request handling action upon successfully handling your request would redirect the user to a confirmation page or somewhere else. Wherever's preferable really :)

Try to approach it logically, what would be the natural chain of events upon POSTing the data? What would you as a user expect to happen?

Regarding your GET action, that is because you are not sending in the parameters o and t, which you then immediately return. Since nothing happens to these parameters in your logic and they are not otherwise specified, they will contain null which is the default value for variables of type string. Are you not intending to retrieve data from the database, rather than supply two parameters only to immediately return them?

Comment: Ok :) so currently the action marked with the post attribute...What should it return instead?

Comment: @ASPCoder1450 How is the case proceeding? Did my answer help you in solving your problem?